# Site doesn't crash after hot refresh only on first load in 3js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I am using ReactJs with react-three/drei. I dont know why the page only works after hot refresh.

Upon first load of page I get Errors:

1. Uncaught Error: R3F: Hooks can only be used within the Canvas component!
2. The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Canvas)> component

and then i get THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.

I looked through the call stack and this was the exception thrown:

```
​
columnNumber: 11
​
fileName: "http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@react-three_drei.js?v=6191d7dc"
​
lineNumber: 18920
​
message: "R3F: Hooks can only be used within the Canvas component!"
​
stack: "useStore@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@react-three_drei.js?v=6191d7dc:18920:11\nuseThree@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@react-three_drei.js?v=6191d7dc:18924:10\nHtml<@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/@react-three_drei.js?v=6191d7dc:20022:7\nrenderWithHooks@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite
<prototype>: Error.prototype
```

once the page is loaded for the first time if I do a hot refresh on any model or page then everything works.

I want to fix this because I cant do a hot refresh in production.

Comment: That's a timing issue, where you're trying to run JS before everything's loaded in, whereas the hot reload doesn't need to wait for anything, the browser already has things loaded. So find out what your library load order is by looking at your network tab.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for your help. However, I check the network and get 200 OK on everything. Maybe I am reading the info incorrectly?

Comment: Look at the timings, not whether they load or not (we already know they'll load successfully from the fact that a hot reload works)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Ah I see what you're saying now, I know which files are not loading in on time. Now to figure out how to change the load order.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have figure it out, thank you so much for your help!